# Best place to get PHP generic code examples

Tags: php, repository

Aside from the PEAR repository, which I find often has quite messy code with a lot of it using old or deprecated methods and techniques, I was wondering if there was a great place  to find simple (and not so simple) PHP examples of some generic functions and good pieces that people have written.

A good example would be the PEAR spreadsheet module I used a while back.  The thing worked but it was written quite messily and if I remember correctly, in PHP 4.

I'd like to find something with well written and well documented code that I can refer to and see exactly how people are doing things and why they are doing things that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/)'s as good a place to start as any, I've particularly found some of the comments on there helpful.

There's also [The PHP Resource Index](http://php.resourceindex.com/), which is mostly a jumping off point to other projects' websites.

Don't forget to look at  [questions tagged PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) on stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm familiar with the PHP manual but that has more examples on different usages of PHP's in built functions... not so much well written specific functions or modules, but thanks.

Comment: @Evernoob - I've edited in the PHP resource index, which might be do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [PHP Classes](http://www.phpclasses.org/). They have a large selection of classes, all with user ratings.

Answer (score 0):

There's also Zend Framework spesific [ZF Snippets site](http://www.zfsnippets.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Github is another good resource, more often than not it is polished code that is updated frequently.

Getting classes from other people is all well and good but keep upgrade-ability in mind, if i'm using someone else's class and need to tweek it i always extend from it.